# LibreOffice Draw - require field fillement before user will save pdf

Tags: pdf, forms, libreoffice-draw

Is that possible to create pdf that will reguire to check one of an Option button (radiobutton) in Group before user will save the file?
If no any Option button will be selected, user will get message that it is required to select one of the Optionbutton.

Something like Save/Save As event (didn't find any).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write PDF scripts for AcroForms and other PDFs, many do have them.

However it is not possible to stop saving a PDF.

So with or without running a scripted pdf, the generic answer has to be NO.

What you can do is mark a field visually as "required" (not all viewers will show that) and ask the user to complete that field if their viewer has such ability.

So from my answer on Stack Eexchange https://stackoverflow.com/a/76887284/10802527 make it a bold in your face piece of text.

Basically PDF readers do not need to run scripts or colours, when showing a form field. Nor can they stop incomplete or separate *ad hoc* submissions, the only way is social engineering.

[image]

Use larger type in vivid colour NOT just at the top, but **close to the signature as possible** to remind the signatory it is their fault if a form is rejected due to error or omissions.

[image]